# Is it possible to auto generate annotated-mapped POJO classes using techniques like Hibernate, JIBX etc?

Tags: java, xml, database, hibernate, jibx

Hibernate can auto-generate schemas from properly annotated POJO classes. And I also know that JIBX can create a data model (set of classes) out of properly structured XML schemas. Is there a way to automaticaly generate annotated-mapped classes from an XML schema? Or is it just possible to run a tool on a set of POJO classes, and expect it to create meaningful annotations on the specified classes? So later on we can create database schemas using these classes. To annotate every class that JIBX produces takes actually more work than manually designing the database schema according to the xml schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hyperjaxb project will generate JAXB classes from an XML schema that contain JPA annotations that could be used to create a database schema.

- http://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb

Comment: thanks blaise, actually i am already aware of jaxb but jibx is certainly more appropriate to our business need right now, we'll use hyperjaxb eventually i guess : )

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! We had the same problem and we ended up developing the POJO generator with [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

By the way, the requirements to these POJOs may strongly vary, so, if such tool exists, it must have quite bloated configuration.